# Singular matrices are Nowhere Dense

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to show that the subset S of all singular matrices is Nowhere dense in Set of all matrices of order n.

What I tried:-

As I need to show closure of S has no interior point . But S is a closed set so it is enough to show S has no interior point.

Initially what I thought was if I take any arbitray matrix A in S then in every open ball of radius r>0 centred at A  will contain a matrix A° with first entry a11+r/2 and rest the same as A.

But it turns out that this matrix may not be non-singular.

How can I fix my argument can anyone help!! 
 Thanks & regards

Comment: You are on the right track. The determinant is a real valued polynomial in the entries (linear in each entry). It can't be $0$ on a whole open patch.

Comment: Yes, you are right but can I find that precise matrix?@EthanBolker?

Comment: You can't find "that precise matrix" without looking at the other entries but you can argue that there is such a matrix.

Comment: I think answer below gives that matrix right @EthanBolker??

Comment: Yes, that (accepted) answer is good enough. But you don't need the theorem on Jordan normal form to finish a proof with my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $A$ in Jordan Normal Form, there exists a diagonal matrix $D$, a matrix $N$ which has only $1$'s on the super-diagonal and $0$'s else, and some invertible matrix $V$ such that $A=V^{-1}(D+N)V$. Then perturb $D$ on its diagonal $0$-entries (by adding $\varepsilon$), name the new matrix $\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}$. Then, $\textrm{det}(\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}+N)\neq 0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$
and hence,
$$
\tilde{A}=V^{-1}(\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}+N)V
$$
is the matrix you want for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small (note that, by construction, $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}=D$ in $L^{\infty}$ and all norms on the matrices are equivalent).

Comment: Yes... that's what the last comment is about. The above matrix is $L^{\infty}$ continuous in $\varepsilon>0,$ so for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, $||\tilde{A}-A||_{\infty}\leq r$. I'm not sure what norm you're using, but the matrices are finite-dimensional, so all norms are equivalent and it doesn't matter.

Comment: I got your point ||A^~-A|| =||V^-1(D_r-D)V||<||V^-1|| ||D_r-D|| ||V||<r. Is this correct ?? WoolierThanThou

Comment: In a Banach Algebra norm (such as the operator norm), you have the last inequality. Then, you get $||\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}-D||\leq K||\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}-D||_{\infty}=\varepsilon$ for some appropriate $K>0$ by equivalence of norms.

Comment: The $L^{\infty}$ norm isn't a Banach Algebra norm (consider a matrix with all $1's$ in a single column and $0's$ else multiplied by a matrix with all $1's$ in a single row and $0's$ else), so it's no longer true that $||CB||_{\infty}\leq ||C||_{\infty}||B||_{\infty}$. Thus, the easiest way to finish would be to let $||\cdot||$ denote the operator norm. Then, there is some $K'$ such that $||\tilde{A}-A||_{\infty}\leq K'||\tilde{A}-A||\leq K'K||V^{-1}||\cdot ||V|| \cdot ||\tilde{D}_{\varepsilon}-D||= K' K ||V^{-1}|| \cdot ||V|| \varepsilon$

Comment: Oh.. that sounds intriguing, I didn't knew that fact, I thought equivalnce of norms gaurantees that also.  thanks a lot @WoolierThanThou

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial $\det(\lambda I -A)$ of $A$ has a zero at $\lambda=0$. It can't vanish in a vicinity of that point. So it's also possible to perturb A along the diagonal to reach a non-singular Matrix.

Comment: But why the diagonals only? @anon

Comment: It is what I can conclude from this approach, namely perturbing A by the identity matrix.